# Which user is running tomcat?

Tags: users, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I have a `Tomcat 7` server running on Amazon EC2 (OS - Ubuntu 12 LTS). How can I find out which user is running `Tomcat` on Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run following command to find out the tomcat process

```
ps auxwww | grep -v grep | grep tomcat
```

From there you will find out the tomcat process and from there you can see which user is starting this.

For eg see the following output

```
vidyadhar@ubuntu:~$ ps auxwww | grep -v grep | grep tomcat
root      1941  0.2  1.7 419224 35208 ?        Sl   Aug12   0:06 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

In above eg **1941** is a tomcat process which is started by **root** user.

If you want to see all the user run below command

```
more /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I recommend piping the output of `ps ...` to `grep -v grep` *before* piping to `grep tomcat` (rather than after). By piping to `grep -v grep` first, you see the helpful highlighting of the matching text, from the `grep tomcat` command (as only the last `grep` command's highlighting is retained).

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep): *look up, signal, or wait for processes based on name and other attributes.*

```
pgrep -fa tomcat
```